Compilation errors while building a C++ project with Android NDK using CMake and Ninja on a Windows platform
edit:

The output of the command with the -H option shows that the correct
headers are being included, but the errors suggest that the types
like int8_t and uint8_t are not being found.

2.tried using only paths that contain no spaces but no change in error


It appears there might be an issue with the order or location of include paths or a specific header is interfering with the proper inclusion of the stdint.h definitions.
I am experiencing persistent compilation errors while building a C++ project with Android NDK using CMake and Ninja on a Windows platform. The project includes multiple C++ source files that require proper integration with the Android toolchain. Despite attempting to resolve the issue, the errors persist, mainly involving the inability to locate standard type definitions such as int8_t, int16_t, etc., from the <cstdint> header.
Environment Details:
Operating System: Windows 10
Android NDK Version: 23.1.7779620
Toolchain File: D:/Resmi Mems/ndk/23.1.7779620/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake
ABI: arm64-v8a
Platform: android-21
Build System: CMake and Ninja
C++ Standard: gnu++14
Command Used:
Remove-Item -Recurse -Force build
cmake -B build -S . -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE="D:/Resmi Mems/ndk/23.1.7779620/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake" -DANDROID_ABI=arm64-v8a -DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-21 -G Ninja
cmake --build build --verbose

Error Messages:
The primary errors encountered during compilation are related to the <cstdint> header, indicating that standard integer types such as int8_t, int16_t, int32_t, etc., are not found in the global namespace.
:\Users\acer\StudioProjects\apptest\app\New folder\ecg_app\csv_processor\csv_processor\new_csv_processor\native>cmake -B build -S . -G Ninja
-- Configuring done (0.1s)
-- Generating done (0.1s)
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/acer/StudioProjects/apptest/app/New folder/ecg_app/csv_processor/csv_processor/new_csv_processor/native/build

C:\Users\acer\StudioProjects\apptest\app\New folder\ecg_app\csv_processor\csv_processor\new_csv_processor\native>cmake --build build
[1/8] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/cwt.cpp.o
FAILED: CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/cwt.cpp.o
"D:\Resmi Mems\ndk\23.1.7779620\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe" --target=aarch64-none-linux-android21 --sysroot="D:/Resmi Mems/ndk/23.1.7779620/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/sysroot" -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS -Dnative_lib_EXPORTS -I"D:/Resmi Mems/ndk/23.1.7779620/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include" -I"D:/Resmi Mems/ndk/23.1.7779620/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++abi/include" -I"D:/Resmi Mems/ndk/23.1.7779620/sources/android/support/include" -I"D:/Resmi Mems/ndk/23.1.7779620/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/sysroot/usr/include/android" -I"C:/Users/acer/StudioProjects/apptest/app/New folder/ecg_app/csv_processor/csv_processor/new_csv_processor/native/include" -DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fexceptions -frtti -stdlib=libc++ -O2 -g -DNDEBUG -std=gnu++17 -fPIC -MD -MT CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/cwt.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles\native-lib.dir\src\cwt.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/cwt.cpp.o -c "C:/Users/acer/StudioProjects/apptest/app/New folder/ecg_app/csv_processor/csv_processor/new_csv_processor/native/src/cwt.cpp"
In file included from C:/Users/acer/StudioProjects/apptest/app/New folder/ecg_app/csv_processor/csv_processor/new_csv_processor/native/src/cwt.cpp:2:
D:/Resmi Mems/ndk/23.1.7779620/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include\cstdint:152:8: error: no member named 'int8_t' in the global namespace
using::int8_t;
     ~~^
D:/Resmi Mems/ndk/23.1.7779620/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include\cstdint:153:8: error: no member named 'int16_t' in the global namespace
using::int16_t;
     ~~^
D:/Resmi Mems/ndk/23.1.7779620/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include\cstdint:154:8: error: no member named 'int32_t' in the global namespace
using::int32_t;
     ~~^
D:/Resmi Mems/ndk/23.1.7779620/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include\cstdint:155:8: error: no member named 'int64_t' in the global namespace
using::int64_t;
     ~~^
D:/Resmi Mems/ndk/23.1.7779620/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include\cstdint:157:8: error: no member named 'uint8_t' in the global namespace
using::uint8_t;
     ~~^
D:/Resmi Mems/ndk/23.1.7779620/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include\cstdint:158:8: error: no member named 'uint16_t' in the global namespace
using::uint16_t;
     ~~^
D:/Resmi Mems/ndk/23.1.7779620/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include\cstdint:159:8: error: no member named 'uint32_t' in the global namespace
using::uint32_t;
     ~~^
D:/Resmi Mems/ndk/23.1.7779620/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include\cstdint:160:8: error: no member named 'uint64_t' in the global namespace
using::uint64_t;
     ~~^
D:/Resmi Mems/ndk/23.1.7779620/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include\cstdint:162:8: error: no member named 'int_least8_t' in the global namespace
using::int_least8_t;
     ~~^
D:/Resmi Mems/ndk/23.1.7779620/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include\cstdint:163:8: error: no member named 'int_least16_t' in the global namespace
using::int_least16_t;
     ~~^
D:/Resmi Mems/ndk/23.1.7779620/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include\cstdint:164:8: error: no member named 'int_least32_t' in the global namespace
using::int_least32_t;
     ~~^
D:/Resmi Mems/ndk/23.1.7779620/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include\cstdint:165:8: error: no member named 'int_least64_t' in the global namespace
using::int_least64_t;
     ~~^
D:/Resmi Mems/ndk/23.1.7779620/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include\cstdint:167:8: error: no member named 'uint_least8_t' in the global namespace
using::uint_least8_t;
     ~~^
D:/Resmi Mems/ndk/23.1.7779620/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include\cstdint:168:8: error: no member named 'uint_least16_t' in the global namespace
using::uint_least16_t;
     ~~^
D:/Resmi Mems/ndk/23.1.7779620/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include\cstdint:169:8: error: no member named 'uint_least32_t' in the global namespace
using::uint_least32_t;
     ~~^
D:/Resmi Mems/ndk/23.1.7779620/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include\cstdint:170:8: error: no member named 'uint_least64_t' in the global namespace
using::uint_least64_t;
     ~~^
D:/Resmi Mems/ndk/23.1.7779620/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include\cstdint:172:8: error: no member named 'int_fast8_t' in the global namespace
using::int_fast8_t;
     ~~^
D:/Resmi Mems/ndk/23.1.7779620/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include\cstdint:173:8: error: no member named 'int_fast16_t' in the global namespace
using::int_fast16_t;
     ~~^
D:/Resmi Mems/ndk/23.1.7779620/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include\cstdint:174:8: error: no member named 'int_fast32_t' in the global namespace
using::int_fast32_t;
     ~~^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.


There are lots of include paths on the command line. Perhaps the compiler picks up a header from the wrong directory?

Have you tried using only paths that contain no spaces? I don't know if that's the problem here, but some parts of the NDK can have trouble with spaces in paths.

My guess would be a conflict in a header name between a system library and the files in C:/Users/acer/StudioProjects/apptest/app/New folder/ecg_app/csv_processor/csv_processor/new_csv_processor/native/include, please show a [mre]

Excessive or conflicting include paths can cause the compiler to pick up the wrong header files.

#include  #include #include #include #include <wchar.h>
#include 
#ifdef ANDROID
#include <android/log.h>
#else
// Define stubs or alternative implementations for non-Android platforms
#endif#include "stdafx.h"
#include "signal.h"
#include "cwt.h"
#include "fwt.h"
#include "ecgdenoise.h"
#include "ecgannotation.h" #include <sys/select.h>
#include 
#include 
#include 
#include 
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#ifdef ANDROID
#include <sys/time.h>
#else
#include <time.h>
#endif

the above headers are the headers of one of the file in  the project. Like are there chances of them conflicting with each other if then what format should I order them

You should [edit] additional information into the question, comments don't support much formatting. Including headers is not likely to be the issue, my guess would be the presence of headers somewhere on the include path which are clashing (have the same filename) with the ndk headers

try building a fresh project that just includes the cstdint header.

 should include <stdint.h> which defines those headers. Copy the clang++ invocation and add the -H option, which prints all headers included. Edit your question with the output. Take a close look at the stdint.h file included, which should define these type synonyms.
